# Shuttle bus from Podgorica town to the airport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, montenegro, tgd, podgorica

It seems tricky, but it's a capital, there must be some public transport to the airport, right?

What I can find online is some outdated posts mentioning there's a shuttle arranged by Montenegro airline from Trg Republiek to the airport, but I can't find any schedule or updated info.

Another solution is take a train, then stop somewhere 0n the road, with more than 1 km to the airport.

To be sure, I would like to take a shuttle. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get from the airport to the city (or from the city to the airport) by train. It is a little bit tricky, because the train station is about 1 km from the airport and trains don't go frequently, but it is doable. You just have to go by foot to the train station called "Podgorica Aerodrom" (it is here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=42.36529%2C19.23443#map=19/42.36529/19.23443 ) and get a train there. In July 2018 I went from the city to the airport by train and it wasn't hard. More info: http://czterycztery.pl/dzialania/turystyka/dojscie_na_lotnisko_w_podgoricy/

Answer (score 1):

As several online sources will show ([shuttledirect](http://www.shuttledirect.com/en/transfers/Podgorica/), [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Podgorica) and to quote [taxipg](http://www.taxipg.com/index.php/en/)):

> Taxi from Podgorica airport to Budva, Dubrovnik, Petrovac, Bar, etc.
>   is the only way of transportation, because there is no shuttle bus...

So you're really going to have to use a taxi if you don't want to take the train option you mentioned, sorry :/

You can book online, or your  hotel/accommodation should be able to order one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can **book a shuttle bus** at advance at **Ryanair** https://airporttransfers.ryanair.com/en and 
**Wizz air** https://wizztransfer.com/index.php?lang=2 from Podgorica airport to Podgorica, Petrova, Sveti Stefan, Budva, Kotor and Tivat. The local company **Go Montenegro** http://www.gomontenegro.me will receive reservations from partners Ryanair and Wizzair and wait for you in the **airport hall or hotels, apartments, main bus stations**

Comment: Welcome to Travel! Please note that whenever you link to your own website, [you must explicitly state so](/help/promotion).